# If or Case within a dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, case

On SQL Server 2008, I have a variable @storename which is a varchar(20) and this statement :

```
SET @query = 'select '+@result1+' '+@colsNull+' into ##tempz 
FROM
(SELECT '+@result2+'
FROM rpPay p LEFT JOIN RPTrs r ON p.ReceiptNo = r.receiptno LEFT JOIN Currencies c ON LEFT(p.paytype,1) = c.POSCurrency
WHERE r.trsdate >= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 101) +''' 
AND r.trsdate <= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @endDate, 101) +''' 
) p
pivot
(sum(amount) FOR CurrencyDesc in('+@cols+')) piv'
execute(@query)
```

I am trying to set the where clause to either all StoreIDs or to what the @storename has. Can I have a IF or case statement in there or something like

```
and r.StoreID = * or r.StoreID = @storename
```

Is there such a thing to use a wildcard in where clause?

As it stands right now I have tried :

```
declare @storename varchar(20)
set @storename = '01'

and ('+@storename+' is null or r.storeId = '+@storename+') -- Error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BK' to data type int.
and r.StoreID like '+@storename+' -- Returns no information, just blank table
```

Also just tried

```
declare @storename varchar(20)
set @storename = '01'
and r.storeid = '''+@storename+'''
```

Which does work and return everything just from store 01 but if I put

```
set @storename = null -- Gives me invalid Object name for the temp table I'm using
set @storename = '' -- give back no results again, just empty table
```

Comment: ##tempz? Can you explain your use case for a global temp table? Are you ever going to have a case where two people will try to execute this code at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you might try:-

```
AND ( @storename IS NULL OR r.StoreID = @storename )
```

Comment: Using and ('+@storename+' is null or r.storeId = '+@storename+') I get  this error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BK' to data type int. The @storename is a varchar(20) not an int

Comment: @JohnZ: You said that you wanted `r.StoreID = @storename` as part of the condition

Comment: @AndriyM - Yes I do, in the database, the storeid can be 01 or XC, it depends on the client on how they call their store. My goal is either to run the select where it selects all stores or the specific name they put in

Comment: @JohnZ: Something is not right. The error message you mentioned earlier clearly suggested that `storeid` was an int. How can it store something like `XC` then? I suspect there's a gap between the issue as you are experiencing it and the one that you've described. I mean, some important information seems to be missing.

Comment: @JohnZ:  By the way '... and ('+@storename+' is null ...' won't work, because NULL won't concatenate.  Does this have to be done with dynamic SQL?

Comment: Main post update, and @gmm Yes it does... thus the whole issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NULL` for `@storename` to mean "all records".

```
declare @storenameComparisonValue varchar(50)
set @storenameComparisonValue =
        isnull(cast(replace(@storename, '''', '''''') as varchar(50)), 'null')
' ... and (' + @storenameComparisonValue + ' is null or r.StoreID = '''
        + @storenameComparisonValue + ''')
```

Comment: Tried the updated post, still gives me the : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BK' to data type int.

Comment: @JohnZ:  Then, as suggested by Andriy M, it seems that StoreID is an `int` and that `@storename` contains `'BK'`.  You can't compare `'BK'` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`r.storeId = '+@storename+')`

storeId is an int and @storename is a varchar so you cannot compare them.

`and r.StoreID like '+@storename+'`

storeID is an int so you can't do LIKE on it.

You probably need to cast @storename to an int or refactor your database so StoreID is a varchar, so they match.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work with

> and r.storeid like ''%'+@storename+'%''